# Template specialization and Function overloading in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, polymorphism, overloading

I am trying to build a static wrapper function that will be able to call member and and non-member function pointers.

What I have come up with is as follows -

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CallAny {
  template<typename F> using ReturnType = typename std::function<typename std::remove_pointer<F>::type>::result_type;

  template<typename F, bool IsMember, typename... Args>
  static ReturnType<F> function_wrapper(Derived* obj, F func, Args... args);

  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static ReturnType<F> function_wrapper<F, true, Args...>(Derived *obj, F func, Args... args) {
    return obj->*func(args...);
  }

  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static ReturnType<F> function_wrapper<F, false, Args...>(Derived *obj, F func, Args... args) {
    return func(args...);
  }

};

struct CallAnyDerived : public CallAny<CallAnyDerived> {};
```

Here `F` is a function pointer type that has to be called with arguments given in `Args...`. `F` might be a C-style function pointer or a member of  class `Derived` which inherits from `CallAny`.

When I try to compile this code, I get an error saying -

```
XXXXXXXXXXX: error: function template partial specialization ‘fucntion_wrapper<F, true, Args ...>’ is not allowed
   static ReturnType<F> function_wrapper<F, true, Args...>(Derived *obj, F func, Args... args) {
                                                                                             ^
XXXXXXXXXXX: error: function template partial specialization ‘fucntion_wrapper<F, false, Args ...>’ is not allowed
   static ReturnType<F> function_wrapper<F, false, Args...>(Derived *obj, F func, Args... args) {
                                                                                              ^
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Function templates cannot be partially specialized, they can only be fully specialized.  Do you really intend to ignore `obj` in the `false` wrapper?  Seems strange.  Can you give me actual end-user-code use cases for this?  How do you intend the `true` and `false` to be passed in?  Oh, and your `ReturnType ` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: what is the point of the `Derived* obj` in the latter specialization?

Comment: This is part of an RPC interface. The pointers to the static functions can be forwarded between machines as void* types. But pointers to member functions cannot. So the wrapper converts the member function call to a static type.
The `Derived*` in the second specialization is unused, but is there primarily to keep a unified interface to the wrapper

Comment: @subzero I'd expect a member function to be translated into a function taking the `this` pointer as its first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you cannot partially specialize a function.  The way around that is to create a helper struct with something like a `static R call(...)`, and partially specialize the helper struct instead.

In this case you don't need template specialization at all, you can use overloading

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CallAny {
  template<typename F> using ReturnType = typename std::function<typename std::remove_pointer<F>::type>::result_type;

  // takes pointer to member function
  template<typename R, typename... Ts, typename... Args>
  static R function_wrapper(Derived* obj, R (Derived::*func)(Ts...), Args... args) {
    return obj->*func(args...);
  }

  // takes everything else
  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static ReturnType<F> function_wrapper(Derived *obj, F func, Args... args) {
    return func(args...);
  }

};
```

Comment: Conjunction junction, what is your `fucntion`?

Comment: Kept it for historical reasons :p

Comment: You should use different `Args...` to avoid no exact match in member method overload. (as `(D*, (D::*)(int), int&)` would should the second overload).

Answer (score 1):

You may use SFINAE:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CallAny {
  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static
  auto
  function_wrapper(Derived* obj, F func, Args&&... args)
  -> std::enable_if_t<
         std::is_member_function_pointer<F>::value,
         decltype((obj->func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
  {
      return (obj->func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static
  auto
  function_wrapper(Derived* obj, F func, Args&&... args)
  -> std::enable_if_t<
         !std::is_member_function_pointer<F>::value,
         decltype(func)(/*obj,*/std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
  {
      return func(/*obj,*/std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

};
```

or tag dispatching:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct CallAny {
  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static
  auto
  function_wrapper(Derived* obj, F func, Args&&... args)
  {
      return impl(std::is_member_function_pointer<F>{}, obj, func, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static
  auto
  impl(std::true_type, Derived* obj, F func, Args&&... args)
  -> decltype((obj->func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {
      return (obj->func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  static
  auto
  impl(std::true_type, Derived* obj, F func, Args&&... args)
  -> decltype(func)(/*obj,*/std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
  {
      return func(/*obj,*/std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```